# Recommend any good sybase database table viewer

Tags: database, sybase

Please recommend good Sybase database table viewer application (for windows 7) to connect to a sybase server on a Linux box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Db Visualizer
http://www.dbvis.com/

You can get a community edition for free.

If you can pay Aqua Data Studio is awesome
http://www.aquafold.com/

Answer (score 0):

DBeaver - http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/

Open source and free.

Supports all popular databases: MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite, Oracle, DB2, SQL Server, Sybase, Teradata, MongoDB, Cassandra, Redis, etc